# pyserial - connect while data is transferred

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

Using **Python PySerial** and trying to connect midst data transfer causes an exception:

```
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf7 in position 1: invalid start byte
```

How do you recover from such an exception? Data is being continuously (with no break whatsoever) transferred. The problem occurs when a device on the other end connects "in the wrong place", misses the start or stop byte and decodes that sequence wrong. But there is no way to get out of that exception.

It's fine to pause the program for a while or discard some data. What's the correct way of reconnecting? Closing and opening port does not help, the problem is the same - it connects at the wrong place. The same problem occurs when reading another data sequence (aka pass exception).

the code used:

```
if serial.in_waiting > 1:
   data = serial.read(serial.in_waiting).decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: `misses start or stop byte` So there is a start byte. Then when you connect, read and discard until you get a start byte.

Comment: I don't know how, that's why I posted this question. How to detect a start/stop byte with pyserial?

Comment: After opening the port, you could try: `serial.read_until(expected=0x03)` This will read until it finds a end-of-text byte (change 0x03 to whatever you use as a stop byte).  You could also check if the first byte returned by this is a start text byte to see if you have a full message.

Comment: You are trying to convert the data read from the serial port to UTF-8 without checking anything. Serial port communication is a minimum of 1 byte unit, and it is a mistake to convert one read data as it is to UTF-8 where one character can be multiple bytes. Also, if there is data called `start or stop byte`, isn't there some binary data called `BCC` that may not be converted to UTF-8? It is better to store the read data in a buffer once, check the format of the received data, and cut out only the part that can be converted to UTF-8 for only valid data and process it.